# Make Text tab open by default in Android Studio

Tags: android, ide, recent-file-list

I use keymaps in Android Studio to save time.

To open "Recent Files" I happen to use the keymap of `CMD`+ `E`, which will open the "Recent Files" pop-up screen.

The problem is that when I then select any of the .xml layout files from this screen, it opens the file **by default** in "Design" mode, instead of "Text".

I prefer to code my layouts in "Text" mode. This means I then have to keyboard shortcut `CTRL`+ `SHIFT` + `->` every time to edit the layout in "Text" mode. How do I open "Text" mode by default.

Note: I would post images, but that is reputation dependent...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/24777497/3315

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Open Settings:

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> Layout Editor -> check the checkbox "Prefer XML Editor"
```

Comment: For me to actually make it work AS restart was needed.

Comment: Great little option. No restart needed for me. Thanks!

Comment: Currently can be found in: `File -> Settings... -> Editor -> Layout Editor`

Answer (score 7):

In newer versions of Android Studio you can find the setting mentioned by Andrey under Preferences > Editor > Layout Editor. ("Prefer XML editor")

A restart is not required.

Comment: Strange, this didn't work for me without restart, and what's worse, still doesn't work after restarting...

Answer (score 5):

Currently it's can be found under
"Preferences" -> "Editor" -> "Design Tools" -> "Default editor mode" section

Answer (score 2):

In Android Studio 3.0 for MacOS

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Editor -> Layout Editor

[image: Screenshot - Prefer XML Option]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac: <kbd>Cmn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> prefer XML...

On Win/Lin: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> prefer XML...